Error creating bean with name 'postgresMlEmbeddingModel' defined in class path resource
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postgresMlEmbeddingModel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ai/autoconfigure/postgresml/PostgresMlAutoConfiguration.class]: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgml]; SQL state [0A000]; error code [0]; ERROR: extension "pgml" is not available Detail: Could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/share/extension/pgml.control": No such file or directory.
Hint: The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.
I have install postgresql 16 and java 21 installed in my machine. After that I create one sample springboot project and try to run that at that time i found this error.
How can I clear this error and run the project? I have tried to search the extension but did not found any to resolve it.

Learn to use markdown to format your posts.

Do you have docker installed?

Well, the message indicates that some code of yours (which you didn't post) tries to run the extension creation statement but can't find the extension file. So if the extension doesn't exist (assuming you already checked that as you described) then you need to provide that file first - if I were you I'd look in the documentation of that extension on how to do that properly.

From the github page of postgresml, it seems you can just start it with docker.
Just use the newest version that you can fine here since I assume it changes often. (There is no latest tag that I can find)
There is also a getting started with docker section where I got this information from:
Prerequisites Windows
Install WSL and Docker Desktop. You can then use Linux with GPUs instructions. GPU support is included, make sure to enable CUDA.
macos and Windows
docker run \
    -it \
    -v postgresml_data:/var/lib/postgresql \
    -p 5433:5432 \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    ghcr.io/postgresml/postgresml:2.9.1 \
    sudo -u postgresml psql -d postgresml

Linux with GPUs
sudo apt install -y \
    cuda \
    cuda-container-toolkit
docker run \
    -it \
    -v postgresml_data:/var/lib/postgresql \
    --gpus all \
    -p 5433:5432 \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    ghcr.io/postgresml/postgresml:2.9.1 \
    sudo -u postgresml psql -d postgresml

For all operating systems, you then need to create the extension after you have connected to the DB.
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgml;
SELECT pgml.version();

